# Converting USD to other currencies

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a complete noob and trying to learn, I want to try to convert USD to other currencies. Been working of this for a few hours and not entirely sure what how to proceed; Was trying to get:

a box where you can enter a dollar amount,
 drop down to select currencies,
 output function to display converted amount.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function usdfunc(){
document.converter.eur.value = document.converter.dollar.value * 0.73640
document.converter.gbp.value = document.converter.dollar.value * 0.60984
document.converter.mxn.value = document.converter.dollar.value * 13.2436
document.converter.jpy.value = document.converter.dollar.value * 102.490
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="converter">
<table border="0">

<td>Dollar Amount: </td><td><input type="text" name="dollar"
onChange="usdfunc()" /></td>
</table>

 <br>


Please select a currency type:
<select id="select">
<option value="eur" onChange="eurfunc()">Euro</option> 
<option value="mxn" onChange="mxnfunc()">Mexican Peso</option>
<option value="gbp" onChange="gbpfunc()">British Pound</option>
<option value="jpy" onChange="jpyfunc()">Japanese Yen</option>
</select>


<br><br>

New Currency:$ <br>
<input id="Calculate" type="button" value="Calculate"
onclick="usdfunc();" />


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question? What's the problem with your code? Please read [ask]. What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: Here's a tip for the HTML: get rid of that `<table>` in there. You don't use tables to contain an input. Also, we have a `<label>` element for the ... wait for it... **label** that goes with an input.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, also was looking to create a function to output the amount of the exchanged currency.

Comment: FYI the onchange attribute goes on the `<select>` not the `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code so that there is a default selection in the select box with instructions, and changing the value of that select box calls the `usdfunc(event)` rather than needing the extra step of pressing a button. [We pass in the <select> event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change#Example_Change_event_on_a_select) and access the value of the selection within the function using  `event.target.value`, then store it in a `targetCurrency` variable.

A [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is used to compute the respective conversion rate.

An empty `p` element sits at the bottom of the doc. Finally, we reference it using document.getElementById() and then assign it's [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) (the text we want to exist between the tags, in this case)

```js
function usdfunc(event){
  
  var targetCurrency = event.target.value;
  
  var conversion;
  var dollarValue = document.converter.dollar.value;
  
  switch (targetCurrency) {
    case "eur":
      conversion = dollarValue * 0.73640;
      break;
    case "mxn":
      conversion = dollarValue * 0.60984;
      break;
    case "gbp":
      conversion = dollarValue * 13.2436;
      break;
    case "jpy":
      conversion = dollarValue * 102.490;
      break;
  }
  
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "$" + dollarValue + " = " + targetCurrency + " " + conversion;

}
```

```html
<form name="converter">
<label>Dollar Amount: <input type="text" name="dollar"></label> 
 <br>
 <br>


Please select a currency type:
<select id="select" onchange="usdfunc(event);">
<option selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
<option value="eur" >Euro</option> 
<option value="mxn" >Mexican Peso</option>
<option value="gbp" >British Pound</option>
<option value="jpy" >Japanese Yen</option>
</select>


<br><br>


<p id="output"></p>
```

**Afterthought**: If you want to use the correct currency symbol, grab the symbols from somewhere online and then in each `switch case`, reassign `targetCurrency` to a string containing the symbol.

```
case "eur":
  conversion = dollarValue * 0.73640;
  targetCurrency = "€";
  break;
```

**PLNKR:** http://plnkr.co/edit/GT65OEdYIv0oyR96BliX?p=preview